# position input after closest span, if it exists, in jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have this function which appends an "input" to the #cursor-start div:

```
var $cursorStart= $("#cursor-start");


$("#main-edit").click( function() {
var cursorExists = $("#cursor").length;
if (!cursorExists){
   $cursorStart.append("<input type='text' id = 'cursor' />");
   $("#cursor").markCursor();

}
   if (cursorExists){
    $("#cursor").focus();

}
```

What I want to do now is add the input after the closest span if it exitst. There are other functions called enterText and markCursor that are called when typing:

```
jQuery.fn.markCursor = function(e){
    $(this).focus();
   $(this).keyup(function(e) {
  $cursorStart.enterText(e);

});

};

jQuery.fn.enterText = function(e){
var $cursor = $("#cursor");
if( $cursor.val() && e.keyCode != 32  ){
    var character = $("#cursor").val();
    $cursor.val("");
    character = character.split("").join("</span><span class='text'>");
    $("<span class = 'text'>"+character+"</span>").insertBefore($cursor);



}
    });
```

I want now to position the input depending on where the user clicks, would .offset() or .position() be of help here?

HTML :

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
```

clicking near a and b would result in an input after "a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listening for clicks on `#main-edit`, listen for the clicks on the `span`s themselves:

```
$('#main-edit span').click(function() {
    $(this).after('<input type="text" id="cursor" />');
});
```

Or use `delegate`:

```
$('#main-edit').delegate('span', 'click', function() {
    $(this).after('<input type="text" id="cursor" />');
});
```

---

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YxfWX/